# Does the Entangle spell count as difficult terrain?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, movement

> A creature that succeeds on a Reflex save is not entangled but can still move at only half speed through the area.

Says the spell.

I wonder if it is actually making the ground it affects become a difficult terrain. If so, then things that can negate difficult terrain's effects (e.g. *Elocator*, *Duelist*'s *Acrobatic Charge* ability, the *Combat Acrobat* feat, etc.) should be able to ignore it.

Or does it simply mean "those abilities won't save you, just slow down anyway"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Entangle and Difficult Terrain are two completely separate phenomena

> ### Difficult Terrain
>
> Difficult terrain hampers movement. Each square of difficult terrain counts as 2 squares of movement. (Each diagonal move into a difficult terrain square counts as 3 squares.) You can’t run or charge across difficult terrain.
>
> If you occupy squares with different kinds of terrain, you can move only as fast as the most difficult terrain you occupy will allow.
>
> Flying and incorporeal creatures are not hampered by difficult terrain.

> ### Entangle
>
> Grasses, weeds, bushes, and even trees wrap, twist, and entwine about creatures in the area or those that enter the area, holding them fast and causing them to become entangled. The creature can break free and move half its normal speed by using a full-round action to make a DC 20 Strength check or a DC 20 Escape Artist check. A creature that succeeds on a Reflex save is not entangled but can still move at only half speed through the area. Each round on your turn, the plants once again attempt to entangle all creatures that have avoided or escaped entanglement.
>
> Note: The effects of the spell may be altered somewhat, based on the nature of the entangling plants.

In spite of Entangled terrain obviously being difficult to navigate, it is not Difficult Terrain, which has a different definition. You will need to have some method of moving which explicitly allows normal movement, e.g. Freedom of Movement, in order to move normally:

> ### Freedom of Movement
>
> This spell **enables you or a creature you touch to move and attack normally** for the duration of the spell, **even under the influence of magic that usually impedes movement**, such as *paralysis*, *solid fog*, *slow*, and *web*.